# Moving entire folder and all its contents to another folder

Tags: batch-file, directory, move, subdirectory

Just need a batch script that will move one folder and all its contents into another folder.

Essentially this

C:\Folder1 to C:\Folder2\Folder 1

Comment: I believe that this was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470880/move-folder-from-one-directory-to-another-in-batch-script

Answer (score 26):

You can use windows native command:

```
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]dirname1 dirname2
```

You can use `move /?`
call for more details.

So, in you case , the command would be:

```
move C:\Folder1 C:\Folder2\
```

If Folder2 doesn't exist, Folder1 will be renamed Folder2.

Comment: If C:\Folder2 already exists, Folder1 will be moved into Folder2: C:\Folder2\Folder1.  If it does not, Folder1 is renamed Folder2.

Comment: Note: For copying a directory from one drive to another, `robocopy dirname1 dirname2 /E /MOVE` has to be used instead (as `move` will give out a nondescript `access denied` error)