# How to move multiple folders in a directory into another folder within the same directory

Tags: batch-file

I have got a series of folders in a directory:

> ```
> C:\directory\folderx
> C:\directory\foldery
> C:\directory\folderz
> etc.
> ```

Those folders amount to approximately one thousand in total, whereby I aim to move about half of them.

I want to move those folders with contents into another folder in the same directory (used a file `listing.bat` to parse the folder titles and sort them, therefore I have obtained the final list of folders of interest in `.txt` format).

> ```
> C:\directory\folderq
> ```

So that the result will look like this:

> ```
> C:\directory\folderq\folderx
> C:\directory\folderq\foldery
> C:\directory\folderq\folderz
> etc.
> ```

I'm not sure whether the following batch command would work for moving multiple folders, I'm actually afraid it will only result in `folderx` falsely being moved in to `foldery` and abort the command:

```
move C:\directory\folderx C:\directory\foldery C:\directory\folderz > C:\directory\folderq
```

Comment: Is this not already answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470880/move-folder-from-one-directory-to-another-in-batch-script

Comment: i'm not talking about moving just one folder to another directory

Comment: That is certainly not the syntax for the MOVE command if you read the help file.

Answer (score 1):

To move all folders within `C:\directory` into `C:\directory\folderq`, you could use the following:

```
for /D %%D in ("C:\directory\*.*") do (
    if /I not "%%~nxD"=="folderq" (
        move "%%~D" "C:\directory\folderq"
    )
)
```

The `if` query prevents `folderq` to be attempted to be moved into itself.

---

If you have a list of folders you want to move in a text file `C:\directory\list.txt` like this...:

> ```
> C:\directory\folderx
> C:\directory\foldery
> C:\directory\folderz
> ```

..., you could use this code:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%D in ("C:\directory\list.txt") do (
    move "%%~D" "C:\directory\folderq"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The command does not work this way, you could specify a directory to move or files but not multiple directories. So you could call the command for each directory once:

```
move C:\directory\folderx C:\directory\folderq
move C:\directory\foldery C:\directory\folderq
```

Or using a very simple script (`moveDirs.bat`) for moving multiple directories:

```
ECHO OFF
for /D %%x in (%*) do move "%%~x" "C:\directory\folderq"
```

you could call this script with: `moveDirs.bat C:\directory\folderx C:\directory\foldery`

Comment: i'll be trying the first choice as it seems more suited for moving specified part of the folders in the directory and not all, although it seems to be tedious a trifle. I consider accelerating the process by working on a data sheet so as to pen down those dull coding lines.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are using Windows, its easiest to just drag and drop the directories into the new folder. If its in the same file explorer window, it moves by default. If not, clicking the SHIFT key while dragging moves instead of copies.